# Web App where I can create questions about HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: web-apps, web-development

I'm a teacher, I give classes about web developing and I'm looking for a web app where I can create challenges, like "Reproduce this layout", "Correct this mistake" or "When the user clicks here, this should happen", I'd like to create this questions with actual code and my students answer or correct with code too

First I'm looking for HTML, CSS and Javascript, but it'd be awesome if also have PHP and SQL

Comment: Check the QA engine theme on Theme Forest. It is a WordPress theme which does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Response from André Monteiro: Actually I'm looking for a service, a service where I can create questions for my students, I don't want to develop the web app.